# Squarespace: Shopping Cart CSS

Tags: css, shopping-cart, squarespace

Im trying to change the shopping cart from the orginal template on Dovetail to something looking like this: http://www.mckenziedave.co.uk/client_files/shopping_layout.png

I know I need to add and customise the css however I cant seem to find any of the orginal CSS from the template either? Can someone help me out or point me in the right direction. I have edited websites in the past and used css however this is the first time on squarespace.

Thank you

Comment: can provide an url to the website or a jsfiddle ?

Comment: Here is an example for one of the items for sale : https://carol-mclean.squarespace.com/shop/tape-weft-extensions-straight-4-wavy

Comment: Have you looked in their help section already? I think primarily you are supposed to use their style editor, http://help.squarespace.com/guides/making-style-changes

Comment: I have looked into the style editor however the options are not there so I need to use the CSS editor only problem is im not sure the css code of the original template (ie what the button is called etc)